# java 8 reduce with parallelStream and stream

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, reduce

I am trying to understand reduce method.  If I use reduce with stream() I get `_ab` and if I use reduce with `parallelStream()` I get `_a_b`.  Should not the output of reduce be same whether we use parallelStream or stream?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class TestParallelStream{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<String> l = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d");
        String join=l.stream()
                     .peek(TestParallelStream::sleepFor)    
                     .reduce("_",(a,b) -> a.concat(b));
        System.out.println(join);
    }

    public static void sleepFor(String w){
        System.out.println("inside thread:"+w);
        try{
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){ }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be, if you had passed valid arguments.  Read the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

> The `identity` value must be an identity for the accumulator function. This means that for all `t`, `accumulator.apply(identity, t)` is equal to `t`.

This is not the case for the inputs you've passed; `"_".concat(t)` is not equal to `t`.  Since you've passed invalid arguments, the behavior of the method is undefined and the method is allowed to do anything, including [making demons shoot out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

I have a hard time telling the behavior you *actually* want, though I suspect you want `.collect(joining("_"))`.  You haven't actually told us your desired output, though.